# Pull files from s3 in different folders and create Dataframe per file

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, io, databricks

I am looking to create multiple dataframes from multiple files under different folders in s3.

So the folders' names are like:

```
Name202301
Name202302
```

and within each of those folders they has .xlsx files called A and B

```
Name202301/A.xlsx
Name202301/B.xlsx
Name202302/A.xlsx
Name202302/B.xlsx
```

I want to take all of the A files and combine them into a df and do the same with all the B files. In reality I have about 30 different files and 20 different folders the files live in to combine into dfs.

I've tried a few different things but nothing has worked... still quite novice at this

This is what I've tried:

```
s3 = b3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
prefix_objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="data/file/folder")
```

Comment: show what you tried.

Comment: normally you could use nested `for`-loops - like `for name in ["A.xlsx", "B.xlsx"]: for folder in ["Name202301", "Name202302"]: path = f"{folder}/{name}" ...`